# SEO viewport meta tag

Tags: html, seo

I'm interested what is the purpose of this meta tag?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Its for responsive webdesign read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 0):

It is not for SEO, it just an instruction how to render the page on mobile devices. You can read more about it here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag